# "Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted" when PHP memory limit is set to 128mb

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, php5

Forgive me if this is the wrong place; was unsure whether to post this on SO or here.

I'm getting the above error from a script, implying that I've reached the limit of 64mb of memory for the script. The problem is, I have the memory_limit in php.ini set to 128M; and according to phpinfo() that's what the memory limit is indeed set to. So why am I getting an error implying I'm hitting the 64m limit of memory when I have the limit set to 128m?

Server config:

- Redhat Linux Enterprise 6.3
- PHP 5.3.3
- Apache 2.2.15
- 8GB of RAM

Comment: Did you restart PHP?

Comment: yes. Restarted Apache as well.

Comment: OK, well, perhaps you could [tell us something about your server](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632).

Comment: Whoops, knew I forgot something. Server config added.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Just finished a big refactor of the script; drastically reduced memory usage and am no longer getting the error.

I should note I was able to work around the error for a while with this php call:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```